# How to redirect everything after "www.mydomain.com/page-url/ " to 404 via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to redirect to a 404 page if a certain url path as been typed or reached?

I mean, if I want every user to be redirected to a 404 page if they get to: www.mydomain.com/page-url/"anything" or whatever that comes after "/page-url/", even if that page exists.

I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^page-url/(*)?$ [R=404,L]
```

But no worked for me.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect `RewriteRule` syntax. Add a `-` dash behind to do nothing of the substitution. And response 404 http response code if pattern `^page-url/.*$`matched.

```
RewriteRule ^page-url/.*$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir, let me clear this there is more than a single page for which I want redirects. "page-url" is not specified!

Comment: then you need to have multiple rules / think about the rewriterule pattern to do what you need